# Convert any character to Upper case globally in all user controls

Tags: c#, winforms

Instead of trying to handle the key typing events at each `TextBox`/`TextArea`/`GridView` cell, I would like to add a global event listener, which will convert all key characters to upper case.

Overriden the below method but unable to replace the type character to upper case.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message m, Keys keys)
{
    var typed = new KeysConverter().ConvertToString(keys);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(typed))
    {
        SendCharKey('M');
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref m, keys);
}

private void SendCharKey(char c)
{
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.HWnd = this.Handle;
    msg.Msg = 0x0102;
    msg.WParam = (IntPtr)c;
    msg.LParam = IntPtr.Zero;
    base.WndProc(ref msg);
}
```

Comment: TextBoxes have a `CharacterCasing` property (sets the `ES_UPPERCSASE`/`ES_LOWERCASE` styles). You can set the Uppercase-only style with it. You don't have a TextArea control in WinForms, maybe you mean a multiline textbox. The DataGridView allows you to manage/customize the EditControl (the TextBox) used to input the data. You can make it uppercase-only the same way. Uppercase/lowercase is more complex than it may appear.

Comment: `this.Handle` is not correct.  That's the form, it has no use for keystrokes.  You meant to use this.ActiveControl.Handle.

Answer (score 0):

To change text in all controls, simply define recursive function and invoke it in event hadnler, something like this:

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // I assume this code will be placed inside Form class :)
  ControlTextToUpper(this);
}

private void ControlTextToUpper(Control control)
{
  control.Text = control.Text.ToUpper();
  foreach (Control ctrl in control.Controls)
    ControlTextToUpper(ctrl); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to add a global event listener, which will convert all key characters to upper case.

A relatively simple way to accomplish this is to register a Application messagefilter.  This is done via the [Application.AddMessageFilter(IMessageFilter) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter?view=netframework-4.8).  In this example, the form itself implements the [IMessageFilter Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter?view=netframework-4.8).

The `PreFilter` method intercepts the [WM_CHAR message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-char)s and determines if the message is for a lower-case character.  If it is lower-case, the message is cancelled an a new mess[age with the upper-case equivalent is sent to the window.

The filter is installed/removed on form activation/deactivation so that it only active for the given form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnActivated(e);
        // install filter on form activation
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
    }

    protected override void OnDeactivate(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDeactivate(e);
        // remove filter on form deactivation
        Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
    }
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        const Int32 WM_CHAR = 0x102;
        bool ret = false;
        if (m.Msg == WM_CHAR)
        {
            char c = (char)m.WParam.ToInt32();
            if (char.IsLower(c))
            {
                char upper = char.ToUpper(c);
                SendMessage(m.HWnd, m.Msg, new IntPtr(upper), m.LParam);
                ret = true;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public extern static IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

}
```